# What is the derivative of the following matrix expression with respect to W?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, implicit-differentiation

What is the derivative of the following matrix expression with respect to $W$?

$J(W)=\log(\det(\operatorname{diag}(WRW^T)))$ where $W$ is a square matrix and $R$ is a symmetric matrix

Where the $\operatorname{diag}$ operator sets all the off-diagonal elements to zero, for example:
  $$ \operatorname{diag} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 5 \\
    1 & 2 & 6 \\
    1 & 0 & 7 \\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 7 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's replace the diagonalization function by a Hadamard $(\odot)$ product with the identity matrix, which is easier to type.
For further convenience, let's define the (symmetric) matrix variable
$$X = I\odot(WRW^T)$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable. Then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 J &= \log(\det(X)) \cr\cr
dJ
 &= d\log(\det(X)) \cr
 &= d\,{\rm tr}(\log(X)) \cr
 &= X^{-1}:dX \cr
 &= X^{-1}:I\odot(dW\,RW^T+WR\,dW^T) \cr
 &= I\odot X^{-1}:2\,{\rm sym}(dW\,RW^T) \cr
 &= 2X^{-1}:(dW\,RW^T) \cr
 &= 2X^{-1}WR:dW \cr\cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial W}
 &= 2X^{-1}WR \cr
 &= 2\Big(I\odot(WRW^T)\Big)^{-1}WR \cr
}$$
In some of the steps above, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and ${\rm sym}$ refers to the symmetrization function
$${\rm sym}(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$

Comment: Thanks! I used a different approach and got the same result.